# How can I correct this "runtime error 1004 method range of object _global failed" error?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to open a file based on a named reference in my excel work book.  My code:

```
Sub OpenCustomerData()
    wb = ActiveWorkbook.Name

    reference = "[" & wb & "]Individual" & "!customer_id"

    customer_id = Range(reference)

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=customer_id.Value & ".csv"
End Sub
```

Stepping through the code, the `reference` looks to me to be right: `[MyBook.xlsm]Individual!customer_id` but I get the 1004 error when I pass that as an argument to the `Range()` function.

Why?

Comment: Shouldn't the sheet name be in quotes? Ex: `[MyBook.xlsm]"Individual"!customer_id`. Does that make any difference?

Comment: @CaffeinatedCoder It doesn't appear to.  I changed to `reference = "[" & wb & "]""Individual""" & "!customer_id"` and still get the error.

Comment: My bad, I believe I found a working method for you. One sec while I post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're in the active workbook anyway, then just use the sheet name and qualify the range:

```
Sub OpenCustomerData()
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Sheets("Individual").Range("customer_id").Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set the names range to a variable like so

```
Set CustID = ActiveWorkbook.Names("customer_id").RefersToRange
Workbooks.Open Filename:=CustID.Value & ".csv"
```

Comment: @Jamie Please see my revised answer and let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use **customer_id** as a range (aka *cell*) reference and retrieve the [Range.Value property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx) out of it in your concatenated string filename then you need to `Set` it.

```
SET customer_id = Range(reference)
Workbooks.Open Filename:=customer_id.Value & ".csv"
```

If you just want **customer_id** as the value of the range to start with then you do not need to `Set` it, but you use it as a variable with a stored value, not as a [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx).

```
customer_id = Range(reference).VALUE
Workbooks.Open Filename:=customer_id & ".csv"
```

Not declaring **customer_id** demonstrates ambiguity as to how it should be used.